# Trouble converting mat to bitmap?

Tags: java, android, opencv, bitmap

I am using OpenCV to detect the similarities between two images. Unfortunately, my line of code that converts my Mat back to a bitmap is causing my app to crash. Does anyone have any ideas what would be causing this? Here is my code:

```
    Bitmap centerBit = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.center);
    Mat center = new Mat();
    Utils.bitmapToMat(centerBit,center);
    Mat resultCenter = new Mat();
    Imgproc.matchTemplate(center,center,resultCenter,Imgproc.TM_SQDIFF_NORMED);
    Bitmap bm = Bitmap.createBitmap(resultCenter.cols(), resultCenter.rows(),Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Utils.matToBitmap(resultCenter, bm); //THIS LINE CAUSING APP TO CRASH
    ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    iv.setImageBitmap(bm);
```

Comment: maybe the image is not in a supported type. It has to be 'CV_8UC1' (gray-scale), 'CV_8UC3' (RGB) or 'CV_8UC4' (RGBA). Normally matchTemplate returns a CV_32F

Comment: @api55 That fixed the app crash, except now it returns a black screen. ANy idea why this could be?

Comment: depends on how you convert it to CV_8U, CV_32F should have values from 0...1, however with matchtemplate it depends on the function used, since it is a math formula. what you can do is normalize the image (NORM_MINMAX, from 0-255). However, what I would do is actually take the max value and create an image with circle over the position of this value, to see which was the biggest value, that will tell you where the match was found